# Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation

I am using numpy interp to interpolate datapoint but was given Cannot cast array data from dtype('

Code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def interpolate_fwd_price(row, fx):
    res = np.interp(row['SA_M'], fx['TENOR_DT'], fx['RATE'])
    return res

df = pd.DataFrame({'SA_M': ['2018-02-28','2018-03-10']})
df['SA_M'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SA_M'])
data = pd.DataFrame({'TENOR_DT': ['2017-02-09','2017-03-02','2017-04-03','2017-05-02'], 'RATE':[1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8]})
data['TENOR_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TENOR_DT'])
df['PRICE'] = df.apply(interpolate_fwd_price, fx=data, axis=1)
```

I did some search and could not figure out what is causing the error. Appreciate your input.

Make some change and it works for interpolating the datetime difference instead of datetime directly. Would still be interested to know why it did not work for interpolating datetime directly.

```
def interpolate_fwd_price(row, fx):
    fx['DT'] = (fx['TENOR_DT'] - row(['SA_M'])).dt.days
    res = np.interp(0, fx['DT'], fx['RATE'])
    return res
```

Comment: When you ask about an error, you should indicate where the error occurred.  Sometimes it helps to see some or all of the traceback.  But I'm guessing that you are trying to do some sort of math, maybe interpolation, that does work with dates.  `np.datetime64` is an array dtype that handles date-times.  It uses 64 bits, but I think that's an integer value, not a float.

Comment: I should mention that the error occurs at the last line:  df['PRICE'] = df.apply(interpolate_fwd_price, fx=data, axis=1)

Answer (score 4):

```
In [92]: data = pd.DataFrame({'TENOR_DT': ['2017-02-09','2017-03-02','2017-04-03','2017-05-02'], 'RATE':[1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8]})
In [93]: data        # object dtype with strings
Out[93]: 
   RATE    TENOR_DT
0   1.0  2017-02-09
1   1.2  2017-03-02
2   1.5  2017-04-03
3   1.8  2017-05-02
In [94]: data['TENOR_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TENOR_DT'])
In [95]: data
Out[95]: 
   RATE   TENOR_DT
0   1.0 2017-02-09
1   1.2 2017-03-02
2   1.5 2017-04-03
3   1.8 2017-05-02
In [96]: data['TENOR_DT']
Out[96]: 
0   2017-02-09
1   2017-03-02
2   2017-04-03
3   2017-05-02
Name: TENOR_DT, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The array version of the dates:

```
In [98]: dt = data['TENOR_DT'].values
In [99]: dt
Out[99]: 
array(['2017-02-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-03-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-04-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-02T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

It can be cast to float using the default `unsafe`:

```
In [100]: dt.astype(float)
Out[100]: array([1.4865984e+18, 1.4884128e+18, 1.4911776e+18, 1.4936832e+18])
In [101]: dt.astype(float, casting='safe')
TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

My guess is that `np.interp` is using the `safe` casting to convert those datetime values to floats.

I haven't tried to do `interp` with dates before, so can only suggest some fixes.  First your dates only differ by day, so we don't need the full `ns` resolution:

```
In [107]: dt.astype('datetime64[D]')
Out[107]: 
array(['2017-02-09', '2017-03-02', '2017-04-03', '2017-05-02'],
      dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

It still won't allow safe casting, but the 'unsafe' casting produces reasonable looking numbers.  You might be able to use those in the interpolation.

```
In [108]: dt.astype('datetime64[D]').astype(int)
Out[108]: array([17206, 17227, 17259, 17288])
```